Does one have multiple degrees of freedom in defining logical states and logical operators of a QEC?
Consider a rotated surface code. Let the surface code have $Z$ stabilizers along the top and bottom boundary and $X$ stabilizers along the left and right boundary.
If I initialize all the physical qubits in $\vert 0\rangle$ and then turn on the stabilizers, I have a logical state - let's call this state $\vert 0\rangle_L$. This is just an arbitrary choice, since I could have called it $\vert 1\rangle_L$ or $\vert +\rangle_L$ or anything else I like.
Now, is it still up to me to decide what is the logical $X$ operator of this code? We choose usually a row of physical $X$ operators to be defined as $X_L$. Given that I have called the surface code's logical state $\vert 0\rangle_L$, do I still have a second freedom of choice in what I define to be $X_L$?
Obviously, once I define $X_L$, the operator that anticommutes with it and commutes with all stabilizers is $Z_L$.

Almost...
Yes, the stabilizers of a code define a space. You are nominally free to pick any pair of states within that to be logical 0 and 1, and hence define logical Z.
You then have freedom to define the logical X to be anything that commutes with the stabilizers and anticommutes with logical Z. So the choice is not entirely arbitrary, but it's partially constrained. For a single qubit, you can visualise the Bloch sphere. I can pick any axis through the sphere to define Z. The equator around that axis gives you all the possible logical Xs.
So, why do I say almost? You're not quite finished. Once you've selected logical X and logical Z, there are two operators that anticommute with both. You have a further choice of which you want to be +Y and which -Y. In particular, that means that your statement

Obviously, once I define $X_L$, the operator that anticommutes with it and commutes with all stabilizers is $Z_L$.

is not so obvious. There are many operators that anticommute with $X_L$ and commute with all the stabilizers (all linear combinations $\cos\theta Z_L+\sin\theta Y_L$).

Thanks! I had two questions: About the first paragraph, can I really pick any two states (that are not identical and are $+1$ eigenstates of all stabilizers) to be $\vert 0\rangle_L$ and $\vert 1\rangle_L$ respectively? Or are there more restrictions? I was doing it the other way i.e. first pick a specific stabilizer state to be logical $\vert 0\rangle$, then define logical $X$ (which is an arbitrary operator that commutes with all stabilizers but not a product of stabilizers itself) and go from there to determine logical $\vert 1\rangle$. Is my procedure also correct?

Ah yes, your procedure also works so long as you ensure that logical X maps your logical 0 to an orthogonal state. But the Z logical is already implicitly defined by the selection of the state.

There are no further restrictions that are mathematically imposed on you for selecting the logical states, although many authors that want to develop further results will typically assume that logical x and z are tensor products of paulis.

Thank you for the clarifications
